# Symfony Manually Log User In

Tags: symfony, symfony4, fosuserbundle

A page exists where a user entity is created (this is outside of the normal registration flow).

When the user is created they should be logged in, a guardHandler is used with an authenticator as shown below.

```
use App\Security\FakeAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\GuardAuthenticatorHandler;

        $response = $guardHandler->authenticateUserAndHandleSuccess(
                $user, // the User object you just created
                $request,
                $authenticator, // authenticator whose onAuthenticationSuccess you want to use
                'main'          // the name of your firewall in security.yaml
        );
```

However the authenticator is a mess, it has only been created for the one method `onAuthenticationSuccess`.

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\AbstractGuardAuthenticator;

class FakeAuthenticator extends AbstractGuardAuthenticator
{
    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
    return false;
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
    throw new \RuntimeException('Unreachable code');
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
    throw new \RuntimeException('Unreachable code');
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
    throw new \RuntimeException('Unreachable code');
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {

    return null;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
    throw new \RuntimeException('Unreachable code');
    }

    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
    {
    throw new \RuntimeException('Unreachable code');
    }

    public function supportsRememberMe()
    {
    return true;
    }
}
```

Lots of methods have to be implemented because the method `handleAuthenticationSuccess` expects a class which implements `AuthenticatorInterface`.

The code works and the user is logged in but it doesn't feel like the cleanest solution, is there another way to log in a user?

FosUserBundle is being used in the project and the following does work, but I am unsure if calling methods on loginManager is supported, I can't find anything in the documentation and I don't want my code to be depend on a feature that could change.

```
\FOS\UserBundle\Security\LoginManagerInterface::logInUser('main', $user, $response);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to use the `loginManager` and its public method `logInUser`, its the cleanest solutions without creating an extra class for a single method.

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Security\LoginManager;

...

public function createUserInControllerAction(LoginManagerInterface $loginManager): Response
{
    $user = new User(); // create user however you like

    $loginManager->logInUser('main', $user, $response);

    return $this->json(['success']);
}
```